# How to keep continue uploading task even when activity and application destroyed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Here i tried to upload data from Adapter(recyclerview) in firebase storage and on success of task put data (for ex:url)in firebase realtime database and also change in sqlite offline database.
Here is my code from adapter onbindviewholder

```
Uri sendingImageURI=Uri.fromFile(new File(messages.getImagepath()));
                            final Uri sendingThumbURI=Uri.fromFile(new File(messages.getThumbpath()));
                            //This is a uploading image task which i want to keep continue after pause, destroy of activity even kill app//
                            filepath.putFile(sendingImageURI).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                                {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                messageFromAdapter.setImageurl(String.valueOf(uri));
                                                rootRef.child("Messages").child(messages.getFromid()).child(ReceiverID).child(messages.getPushkey()).setValue(messageFromAdapter, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
```

Here i want to implement uploading task keep running in

- activity goes to pause state.
- activity destroyed
- totally exit of app even when swiped app from recent item

In sort

```
if(uploading task is start)
{
keep running in background until finish or exception  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement Services in your App, Services are used to run on background, Like downloading, Uploading something

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: You said used background service. How to write these code?

Comment: You should have to check it out https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services